# Keeping an image centred, whilst it changes size by % with browser size?

Tags: jquery, css, image, resize

How do I centre this image but also keep the image size as a percentage so it changes size with the browser? I have been playing around with the css on this image here to get it to resize the height as well as the width http://www.georgewoolfe.com/home.html

this is the css:

```
#image {
    bottom: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 -40%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 56px;
    width: 80%;
}

#image img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I was also wondering if there might be a bit of jQuery that would do this?

I found this website that does exactly what I mean http://www.laurabartlettgallery.com/exhibitions/bravo-zebra/

Thanks
Angela

Comment: I can't see a question here.

Comment: Thank you gdoron. The question is: "How do I centre this image but also keep the image size as a percentage so it changes size with the browser?"

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imageWrapper">
    <img src="http://www.georgewoolfe.com//images/Cecily-Brown_CecilyBrown02.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#imageWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
#imageWrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 433px;
}
```

Comment: thanks. This is kind of what I had to start with. I think this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:
html:

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="img" />
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".img").css('position','absolute');
//width of screen
var width = screen.width;
//width of image
var img_width = jQuery(".img").width();
//get image left prop for absolute position
var left = (width-img_width)/2;
jQuery(".img").css('left',left);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However it seems to push the image to the right off the screen. Do I need to apply any css to this, or give the image a size?

Comment: I don't think because we get screen resolution with jquery, so if screen with be bigger also our left property went bigger. I try this in a different resolution but I get same result.You must delete right & left property in your css code.

Comment: you can replace .img class with #image id because you put image in a div with #image id, it must work

Comment: ok..it kind of works but as browser changes size it doesn't stay centred. I must be doing something wrong? http://www.georgewoolfe.com/home.html

Comment: in which browser it doesn't work? did you try with deleting right & left in your css and this jQuery code ?